# Give Value to UIWebkit and change instantiate ViewController [Swift 4]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a tableView in my first ViewController. One of its functions is this one

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")

    let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let webViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webViewController") as! webViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewController, animated: true)
}
```

As you can see I want to change the viewController when an row is selected and based on the selection I want to present a Website on the next ViewController. I don't know how to pass the row value to the next ViewController or set the webView in this function.

I want to open my urls like this, but probably in a if-else statement for each row one url.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string:"https://www.google.com")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    angebotWebView.load(request)

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: how are you loading the url in your current implementation of `webViewController`?

Comment: @hardikparmar updated

Comment: I've added my answer. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a String Variable in Your `webViewController`:

```
var urlString: String = ""  // here

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let url = URL(string: urlString) // put here
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
angebotWebView.load(request)
         OR
if let urlString = urlString, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    angebotWebView.load(request)
}



}
```

And in your this method:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")

let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let webViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webViewController") as! webViewController
webViewController. urlString = yourUrlArray[indexPath.row]  // call it here
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You made my day Sir. Thank you very much :)

Comment: The force unwrapping is not a good practice in general. (`url!` in this code)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `url` out of the `viewDidLoad` and then change it's value when you are creating the instance in the `didSelect` like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

var urlString:String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let urlString = urlString, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        angebotWebView.load(request)
    }

}
```

in the tableView's didSelect method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")

    let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let webViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webViewController") as! webViewController
    webViewController.urlString = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Here, the `tableViewDataSource` is the source you are using to display the list.

Answer (score 1):

First your need to create var in your webViewController e.g

```
var url: String?
```

then call webViewController like below

```
if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webViewController") as? webViewController {
            vc.url = //indexPath.row
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

        }
```