# Why a change in my firebase database makes my app crash

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, webview

I am building an application with `WebView` and `Firebase` as database. The url used to load the vewView comes from the database.

I have implemented both `WebView` and `Firebase` correctly but the problem is that when I change an url in the database, my app crashes. It basically saying that the url is nil...which is not in reality since the new url is completely valid.

Even when I rebuild my app, the error still continues....

```
class ViewController:  UIViewController {
var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
var nextUrl = "https://www.google.co.uk/"
func retrieveUrl () {
    dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("EXAMPLE")
    dbRef.observe(.value) {
        (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let url = value["url"]!
        self.nextUrl = (url as! String)
        print (nextUrl)
        print ("webview is about to load")
        let request = URLRequest (url: URL(string: nextUrl)!)
        self.webView.load(request)
        self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
    }
    print ("function observe is called")
}

override func viewDidLoad () {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    retrieveUrl()
}
```

Here is the fatal error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: The error is simply saying you are unwrapping a nil value that's why it is crashing try  to avoid this sign `!` in your code

Comment: Yes but the url is not nil since I just changed it in my database, I did not delete it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446766/give-value-to-uiwebkit-and-change-instantiate-viewcontroller-swift-4/53446986#53446986. see this

Comment: sorry I do not get it @wings. There is no reference to any database in the question you indicated?

Comment: My guess is `let url = value["url"]!` is what's throwing the error. However, we don't know that for sure because you've not told us which line is crashing. If it is that line it's because whatever is in the EXAMPLE node does NOT contain a direct child node of *url*. If we could see your structure, it would help. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: The error comes from this line: let request = URLRequest (url: URL(string: nextUrl)!). It is basically saying that nextUrl is nil but it is not. I can see it when I print it. In fact, the app works perfectly fine except if I change the data in the child node url. I mean the first time I built this app, everything was great and since I have changed the data in the url, I have started to have this problem.

Comment: ok... So doing some basic troubleshooting here - what does the `print(nextUrl)` line print? Again, including your structure will generally prevent the question from being closed by others.

Comment: sorry I am beginner. print(nextUrl) is not nil I can see the url in the console

Comment: {
  "Big Icons" : {
    "GengisKhan" : {
      "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/malro-v1-c7f7f.appspot.com/o/Gengis%20Khan%20statue%20portrait.jpg?alt=media&token=3d659f3b-db68-4f23-9002-a6bd76fb3ccf"
    },
    "GustaveCourbet" : {
      "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/malro-v1-c7f7f.appspot.com/o/gustave-courbet-autoportrait-desespere.jpg?alt=media&token=8e32b8f3-7374-4c38-952c-91e8e2a2e162"
    }
  },
  "EXAMPLE" : {
    "url" : "https://www.google.co.uk"
  }
}

Comment: I can tell you what part of the issue is, but again, without seeing your structure, I cannot tell you how to fix it. What you're trying to do with that code is also a bit unclear. The issue is how the use of vars - it's made the code difficult to read and easy to make mistakes. There's a local var `var nextUrl = "https://www.google.co.uk/"` but you've also got a class var by the same name `self.nextUrl = (url as! String)` which is very confusing. The other issue is when observing by .value, any time that node changes, the closure code will be called so you have to deal with changed child data

Comment: Oh - and since you're new... If you want to get someones attention here on SO, when commenting, include their name with an @ symbol. So @bablack will notify you that I responded.

Comment: @Jay: thank for trying to sort this out. I put my database structure above. I am trying to retrieve an url from my database and then use it for loading a web view. So I use a var nextUrl and change its value with the observe method so that is why nextUrl = url. Again, the code works BUT a change of value in the database makes nextUrl to become nil....even if the new value is a valid url

Comment: Please do not put code or structures in comments as they are impossible to read. Include code and structures as TEXT in your *question* so we can read it. And as mentioned in prior comments, do not use links.

Comment: You're printing the `String` you retrieved from Firebase. It is not nil. You are then trying to create a `URL` by passing it the `String`. The initializer that takes a `String` returns an optional URL which means it can return nil. If it does return nil and you force unwrap it as you are doing, it will crash. Use `if let url = ...` and fix your Strings in Firebase to ensure they can be properly converted to URLs. In short, you are crashing because your String could not be converted to a URL.

Comment: @Don. Big thanks ! it is now working :  the url I tried to use cannot be converted to URL....for a reason I cannot tell at the moment. You are absolutely right. Next time instead of challenging my code I will more challenge this kind of basic assumptions. You saved my day!